# Laravel Firebase Admin not validating valid token

Tags: laravel, next.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

***TLTR:*** *Looking to improve authentication flow with NextAuth and FirebaseAuth when having a 3rd Party API call that fetches workspace and revalidates Bearer Token (using firebase-admin) upon call.*

Hey, I encountered an issue while fetching content from a Laravel API.

I am using the Next.js App Router with NextAuth and FirebaseAuth.

The flow goes like this: I pass login details to signInWithEmailAndPassword, then I use signIn('credentials') to pass the tokenId. During the signIn flow, I send a POST request to get the workspace info, ensuring a user is linked to a workspace.

**CredentialProvider (nextAuth)**

```
  authorize: async ({ idToken }: any, _req) => {
    if (idToken) { 
      try { 
        const decoded = await firebaseAdmin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken); 
        const scheme = await getSchemeOnLogin(idToken); 
        return { ...decoded } 
      } catch (err) { 
        console.error(err);           
      }         
    }
      return null;  
  }
```

**getWorkspaceInfo**

```
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try { 
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
      await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/workspace', { 
        method: 'POST', 
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
          Authorization: Bearer ${token}, 
        },      
      })       
      .then(async (res) => { 
        if (!res.ok) { 
          reject('Error Occurred while fetching user data');
        }
        const responseData = await res.json(); // Save to local storage
        console.log(responseData);
        resolve(responseData); 
      }); 
    } catch (err) { 
      reject(err);
    }
  });
```

On the backend, I revalidate the token I receive using firebase-admin, after which I either send a 200 status or a 401.

```
  public function login(Request $request) {
    if (!$this->isTokenValid($request)) { 
      return $this->getJsonResponse("error", "User not Logged In",sonResponse::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED); 
    }
    return $this->getJsonResponse("success", "Successfully Obtained Workspace Details", JsonResponse::HTTP_OK, $infoString);   }
```

The issue arises when I send the request to Laravel. It keeps returning a 401 status. What helped was implementing a timeout of 3 seconds, which is rather hacky.

Thanks!